# Extract list with all the data sources I have in a Power BI dashboard

Tags: powerbi, datasource, powerbi-desktop

I wanted to know if there is a way to extract a list with all the data sources or if someone knows a python script or similar to get this information.

Thanks.

At the moment I only found one code but it was to download the data per table. I want to make inventory of all the tables I have with their respective data source, not with the data that contains the table.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is via Power BI Rest API. You can get a list of Data Sources for a Dataset.
[Datasets - Get Datasources In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/get-Datasources-In-Group).

If your truly mean Dashboard, then via the API again, you can list all the tiles, and in turn it will give you the datasets of each, then in turn, you can get their datasources.